# .htaccess - complicated conditions

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I've been trying to wrap my head around .htaccess for most of the weekend, but I keep stumbling; I can get the server to work with one set of rules, but no more than one at a time.

My application is made up of several pages:

- The Homepage pulls in content from the Detail page, (as well as content that the Detail page doesn't include), with an optional query string argument; e.g. `?s=item-name`
- The Detail page pulls in content with an optional query string argument (the same argument as the homepage; e.g. `?s=item-name` - this would refer to exactly the same content)
- A Collection page
- A Related page

Each of these pages is a php file in the document root (index.php, detail.php, collection.php, related php).

What I would like to achieve:

- The user should be able to go to `mydomain.com/detail/` or `mydomain.com/detail` (so allow trailing slashes) instead of `mydomain.com/details.php`
- If present, the query string argument (`?s=item-name`) should be entered after the page's trailing slash (so `mydomain.com/item-name` instead of `mydomain.com/?s=item-name`; `mydomain.com/detail/item-name` instead of `mydomain.com/detail.php?s=item-name`. This would be the case for all pages, so setting the rule on one page at a time seems rather cumbersome...

This is what my .htaccess file looks like at present, after much fiddling:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?s=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This allows the homepage to pull in the correct content, and I'm sure it's not too far off allowing *any* page to do the same, but I can't quite fathom it.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone was able to answer the question over at Stack Overflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388636/htaccess-redirecting-several-pages

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the first part of the URL, and us it to test if it matches one of your php scripts, like this:

```
RewriteCond $1.php              -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)       $1.php?s=$2
```

Comment: Not working I'm afraid... with or without the trailing slash, I get a file not found error.

Comment: My example was a suggestion that you could work from. In order to make it work in your case the best thing to do is enable rewritelog, so you can see what is going on. If you get a "file not found" it could be that it is rewriting...